# Oracle SQL Group Over Integer Range

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Using Oracle 11g.

I have one table that holds a list of student IDs and marks. Another lookup table holds the boundary values for each grade.

```
STUDENT_MARKS:
STUDENT_ID  STUDENT_MARK
   1            20
   2            60
   3            90
   4            20

GRADE_LOOKUP:
GRADE_ID    GRADE   LOWER_MARK  UPPER_MARK
  1           A         80         100
  2           B         50          79
  3           C          0          49
```

I'm trying to write a query to the returns a count of students in each grade boundary. For example:

```
STUDENT_GRADE   STUDENT_COUNT
  A                  1
  B                  1
  C                  2
```

I've wrote the following code which returns the correct results, however the real data contains around 40 'grade' boundaries. As such the code below becomes rather clunky. I'm ideally looking for a way to produce the same result using a built in method, along the lines of GROUP.

```
SELECT  'A'               AS STUDENT_GRADE,
        COUNT(STUDENT_ID) AS STUDENT_COUNT
FROM STUDENT_MARKS
WHERE STUDENT_MARK >= (SELECT LOWER_MARK FROM GRADE_LOOKUP WHERE GRADE_ID 
                       = 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT  'B'               AS STUDENT_GRADE,
        COUNT(STUDENT_ID) AS STUDENT_COUNT
FROM STUDENT_MARKS
WHERE STUDENT_MARK >= (SELECT LOWER_MARK FROM GRADE_LOOKUP WHERE GRADE_ID 
                       = 2)
AND STUDENT_MARK <= (SELECT UPPER_MARK FROM GRADE_LOOKUP WHERE GRADE_ID 
                     =2)
UNION ALL
SELECT  'C'               AS STUDENT_GRADE,
        COUNT(STUDENT_ID) AS STUDENT_COUNT
FROM STUDENT_MARKS
WHERE STUDENT_MARK <= (SELECT UPPER_MARK FROM GRADE_LOOKUP WHERE GRADE_ID 
                       = 3);
```

Setup code included below. Thanks for any help.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT_MARKS
(
    STUDENT_ID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    STUDENT_MARK INTEGER
);

INSERT ALL
    INTO STUDENT_MARKS (STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_MARK) VALUES (1, 20)
    INTO STUDENT_MARKS (STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_MARK) VALUES (2, 60)
    INTO STUDENT_MARKS (STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_MARK) VALUES (3, 90)
    INTO STUDENT_MARKS (STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_MARK) VALUES (4, 20)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE GRADE_LOOKUP
(
    GRADE_ID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    GRADE      VARCHAR2(10),
    LOWER_MARK INTEGER,
    UPPER_MARK INTEGER
);

INSERT ALL
    INTO GRADE_LOOKUP (GRADE_ID, GRADE, LOWER_MARK, UPPER_MARK) VALUES 
        (1, 'A', 80, 100)
    INTO GRADE_LOOKUP (GRADE_ID, GRADE, LOWER_MARK, UPPER_MARK) VALUES 
        (2, 'B', 50, 79)
    INTO GRADE_LOOKUP (GRADE_ID, GRADE, LOWER_MARK, UPPER_MARK) VALUES 
        (3, 'C', 0, 49)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh?  Just do a join and `group by`:

```
SELECT gl.GRADE, COUNT(*) AS STUDENT_COUNT
FROM STUDENT_MARKS sm JOIN
     GRADE_LOOKUP gl
     ON sm.student_mark BETWEEN gl.LOWER_MAKR and gl.UPPER_MARK
GROUP BY gl.GRAdE
ORDER BY gl.GRADE;
```